# How to plot a lign spanning these two graphs?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, graph, graphics

Consider the following figure:

```
mainplot = ggplot(mtcars, aes(y=mpg,x=wt)) + geom_point() + theme_classic(15) + ylim(c(5,40)) + geom_hline(yintercept=c(15,25), color="red")

gg = ggplot(data.frame(mpg=0), aes(x=mpg))
f = function(mpg,center) {exp(-(mpg - center)^2/(20))}
f15 = function(mpg) {f(mpg,15)}
f25 = function(mpg) {f(mpg,25)}

sideplot = gg + stat_function(fun = f15, linetype="dashed") + stat_function(fun = f25, linetype="dashed") + theme_classic(15) + scale_x_continuous(name=NULL,limits=c(5,40)) + coord_flip() + ylab("f") + theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) + geom_vline(xintercept=c(15,25), color="red")

multiplot(mainplot, sideplot, layout=matrix(c(1,1,1,2),nrow=1))
```

[image]

As the figure is made of two independent graphs, the red horizontal lines are interrupted. Is there any way I can make it a continuous line?

It is possible that the easiest solution consists at using Adobe Illustrator (or some equivalent) to modify the figure.

Answer (score 2):

Not really a solution but a work around.

1. Reduce the margins to stick the two graphs together
2. Make your line a dashed line
3. Remove the y axis line of the sideplot

---

```
mainplot = ggplot(mtcars, aes(y=mpg,x=wt)) + geom_point() + theme_classic(15) + ylim(c(5,40)) + geom_hline(yintercept=c(15,25), color="red", linetype="dashed") + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,0,1,1), "cm"))

sideplot = gg + stat_function(fun = f15, linetype="dashed") + stat_function(fun = f25, linetype="dashed") + theme_classic(15) + scale_x_continuous(name=NULL,limits=c(5,40)) + coord_flip() + ylab("f") + theme(axis.line.y=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) + geom_vline(xintercept=c(15,25), color="red", linetype="dashed") + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,0), "cm"))

multiplot(mainplot, sideplot, layout=matrix(c(1,1,1,2),nrow=1))
```

[image]